# cypress.io and hidden element not present i DOM

Tags: cypress

I need to check if a text ("Skadesaken min") is present on the next page I am navigating to using this code:

```
describe('Folg skade Test', function() {
it('Enter the app', function() {
cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/')
})
it('Select claim', () => {
cy.get('#app > section > article:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(2)').click()
.next().should('contain', 'Skadesaken min>')
})
})
```

Using the selector when inspecting the element in cypress developer tool I get this:

```
#app > section.col-md-9 > article > h1.hidden-xs
```

However the error when replaying the script says that the element is

"cy.next() failed because this element is detached from the DOM."

any idea how to solve this?

Comment: It seems the elements are re-rendered or removed. Please try to select the element again by starting a new chain after the click as cy.get($selector).should(...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the original element got removed from the dom and a new one went in its place

You can get around this easily.

```
const selector = '#app > section > article:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(2)';
cy.get(selector).click();
cy.get(selector).should('contain, 'Skadesaken min>')
```